# How to determine Parcel Neighbors?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, parcel

[image]

i like to get the neighbors of the Parcels "P1" like following :

From B1 to B2 => P5

B2 => P4

From B2 to B3 => P3

From B3 to B4 => P2

From B4 to B1 => P6

i like to make this process automatic by a GIS software like ArcGIS or Postgis, i have thought to make a buffer of the parcel P1 , to get the lines of the boundary of P1 but i will not get the parcel P4 as neighbor .

any solution to get the neighbors like described above.

Comment: This will need some topology-enabled GIS software for sure. So either PostGIS 2, GRASS (has topology, but not sure how to utilize it) or ArcGIS I suppose.

Comment: In Esri's workstation/coverage days this was a SELECT ADJACENT using the ARC (rather than NODE) option to get neighbours that shared a line rather than a node.  I could not find a desktop/geodatabase equivalent in a quick search just now so am interested to see what this question uncovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using but, since 10.1, there has been a [Polygon Neighbors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000) tool which I think would make this much easier to do:

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
>   coincident edges, or nodes).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to make the possible solution simpler but it seems to be the only solution, but i like to have any suggestions .

- from polygons make lines (arcs) => lines.
- buffer polygons with 3m => polygon_buffer.
- make spatial join between polygon_buffer and lines with "one to many" , to get all the polygons touching the lines => sp_lines_buffer.
- for every polygon get its boundary lines, from "sp_lines_buffer" to get neighbor polygon for every line.

For Arc based adjacent it's enough , but for adding node based adjacent , we need to add those steps:

- from polygons get vertices => nodes.
- make spatial join between polygon_buffer and nodes with "one to many" , to get all the polygons touching the nodes => sp_nodes_buffer.
- take a node based neighbors only if the number of neighbors per node is > 3. if not we will ignore the node.

Answer (score 2):

I would think using intersects would work.  Let's say pid is your parcel ids

```
SELECT p1.pid, array_agg(b2.pid) As neighbors 
FROM parcels As p1 INNER JOIN parcels As b2 ON ST_Intersects(p1.geom, b2.geom)
WHERE p1.pid != b2.pid
GROUP BY p1.pid
```

If you would prefer a string instead of an array and are using PostgreSQL 9.0+, you can use

```
string_agg(b2.pid, ',') As neighbors
```

For lower versions of PostgreSQL

```
array_to_string(array_agg(b2.gid),',')
```